# Firebase Realtime database data can be read but does not appear in the database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having a problem that I don't really understand but I will do my best to explain it, I have upgraded Android Studio from version 3.6.1 to version 4.1.3 and since then my Firebase Realtime Database is not working properly, when I add data to the database nothing appears in the Firebase console but when I retreive the data in my app it appears but not from the first time, I had to leave the app and come back to it to see the data appears in my Recycler view (before android studio upgrade everything was working fine including writing to and reading from the database).

here is the code that I use to write to my database:

```
 FirebaseDatabase database =    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

 database.setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);

 DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("Users");

usersRef.child("+201111111111").setValue(new UsersHelperClass("+201111111111","",""));

usersRef.child("+202222222222").setValue(new UsersHelperClass("+202222222222","",""));
```

And here is my Realtime database rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
 ".read": "now < 1631052000000",  // 2021-9-8
 ".write": "now < 1631052000000",  // 2021-9-8
}
}
```

p.s: if there is any file/code is needed please tell me and I will provide it.

what I tried to solve this problem:

1- looking in my Logcat to understand what is going on but I couldn't.

2- searching on Google and Stackoverflow to find a similar problem but I didn't .

3- copying the code and resources file to a new project and deleting the old project.

4- deleting the Firebase console project and starting a new one and adding my app to it.

5- deleting the build files of my project.

6- changing the package name of my project.

these are what I remember since I am stocking in this problem since a week and all of these steps didn't solve my problem and I feel lost here so I any help to understand this and solve it will be very appreciated.

Comment: There's many things that could be going wrong there. My first debugging step would be to write a simpler value, such as `usersRef.child("+201111111111").setValue(true)`. If that doesn't work, you know the problem is not in your `UsersHelperClass` and we can stop caring about that. Next step would be to hard-code the URL for the database, instead of depending on it coming from your `google-services.json`. You can do this with: `FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL to database here")`.

Comment: Have you tried what Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for replying , there isn't any problem in the UserHelperClass or code generally because everything worked fine before I upgraded Android Studio and I tested that code many times before, I tried to hard code the URL for the database but noting changed

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else faced this problem, I returned back to Android Studio 3.6.1 and finally the problem solved and I am able to continue working on the project, so basically as someone else advised me never upgrade Android Studio while working on a project.